# Convert String to CLOB in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have large text which is in String format. I would like to know how to convert that String into CLOB. I'm using Spring data JPA, Spring boot.

I have tried using

```
clob.setString(position, string)
```

Comment: Please provide your code where you are facing this issue, you just mentioned your try.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Why are you using that low-level API with Spring Data? Can we take a step back and understand what you're trying to do? You shouldn't use Clob directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without dragging the question further I want to answer it simply.

In Spring Data JPA there should be an entity which is String and needed to be saved as CLOB in DB. So, the CLOB column of entity should look like this.

```
@Entity
public class SampleData {
    // other columns 

    @Column(name="SAMPLE", columnDefinition="CLOB NOT NULL") 
    @Lob 
    private String sample;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Then you should have a Repository like below

```
public interface SampleDataRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SampleData, Integer> {

}
```

Now in Service method you could do something like below

```
@Service
public class SampleDataService {

    @Autowire 
    SampleDataRepo repo;

    public SampleData saveSampleData() {
        SampleData sd = new SampleData();
        sd.setSample("longtest");

        repo.save(sd);
    }
}
```

This is how the String data is saved as CLOB in DB.

Comment: Thank you Avinash. All I did was added  @Lob  on top of the column and it works like charm.

Comment: Thank you everyone for looking into this issue.

Comment: Can I do the same but with File type instead of String?

Comment: Using String for a CLOB will cause major performance issues on large strings. I recommend using java.sql.Clob instead.

Comment: @Anass can you explain how would it be using java.sql.Clob? Maybe add an answer to this question. Thank you!