# Failed to read results from Spring-boot SQL query

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, clob

I am trying to read the data fetched from the data base using the following query from the repository interface:

```
public interface EventObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<EventObject, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select tb.content from table0 tb where tb.id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> find(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Below is a sample snapshot of the results I got from this query, which is stored into a java list: `List<String> results`

```
[clob1: '{"identity":0,"original_text":"some text","rowid":2}', clob2: '{"identity":2,"original_text":"some text","rowid":3}', clob3: '{"identity":3,"original_text":"some text","rowid":4}', clob4: '{"identity":4,"product.name":"some name","original_text":"some text","commodity.name":"some name","rowid":5}']
```

However, when I was trying to access content of the list using for instance:

```
results.get(1)
```

I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] 2018-10-22 13:44:45.113 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Cla
ssCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy164 cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy164 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What should I do properly to get the result string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to CLOB in Spring data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470901/convert-string-to-clob-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: That seems to work differently in SpringDataJPA: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections (Projections) - Either define an interface or a DTO object that has a `String getContent()` method and use `List<ThatInterfaceOrClass> find(..`. Spring will then implement that interface at runtime with a dynamic proxy or populate the DTO. Not sure what interface it's trying to proxy here but it's obviously not `String` (and can't because not an interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with the help of CLOB.

First thing I did is to change the the String to CLOB inside the class definition as follows:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="text")
@Lob
private String content;
```

By adding the @Lob, the String will be saved to CLOB inside DB as suggested in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470901/convert-string-to-clob-in-spring-data-jpa). Then to retrieve the data, the repository query will return a list of CLOBs as shown below:

```
public interface EventObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<EventObject, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select tb.content from table0 tb where tb.id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Clob> find(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

After getting the data into a list of CLOBs, I need to convert each CLOB into a string using InputStream and IOUtils. For instance, to get one item from list:

```
InputStream stream = results.get(1).getAsciiStream();
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(stream, w);
String sample = w.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning `results.get(1)` to `String variable`, you may check the type of the data in the list by `results.get(1).getClass()` and then try to assign the result to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you are trying to access the first object from the entire list for that you need to get all the data coming into a List and then try to get(index) from the List.

Eg: List listEmp=empRepository.findAll().get